# route different proxy based on subdomain request in nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have one dedicated server in that server I deployed 5 nodejs application.

```
domain name: www.nnd.com
dedicated server ip: xxx.xx.x.60
```

I had domain which is pointed to my dedicated server ip.

sub domains are :

```
app1.nnd.com pointed to xxx.xx.x.60
app2.nnd.com pointed to xxx.xx.x.60
app3.nnd.com pointed to xxx.xx.x.60
app4.nnd.com pointed to xxx.xx.x.60
app5.nnd.com pointed to xxx.xx.x.60
```

now in nginx configuration file based on the subdomain I need to route proxy.
Example:

```
{
    listen:80;
    server_name:xxx.xx.x.60
    location / {
        #here based on subdomain of the request I need to create proxy_pass for my node application 
    }
}
```

Is there any condition and how can I get the original domain name from proxy header?

Answer (score 67):

create a virtual host for each

```
server {
  server_name sub1.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:xxxx;
  }
}
server {
  server_name sub2.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:xxxx;
  }
}
```

And go on, change the port number to match the right port.

Comment: i am just map the dedicated ip to my sub-domain.so domain name i hosted it out side and in that settings i mapped with my dedicated ip.

Comment: so how can i get original proxy host name

Comment: I think I'm missing something, isn't all the skin subdomains ponting to the same IP? What so you mean the original host name

Comment: see when ever i ping app1.nnd.com address the request will come to my dedicated server xxx.xx.x.60 now the nginx $http_host variable contain  my dedicated server ip xxx.xx.x.60, so now where can in get the app1.nnd.com which nginx variable might contain that information

Comment: are you using the load balancing server block ? are the subdomains on a different server?

Comment: subdomains on different server

Comment: app1,app2,app3,app4,app5 all are different node sever running on different port in same dedicated server

Comment: proxy_pass requires the url to  be prefixed by the protocol on nginx 1.10.3, i had to add the prefixes to restart nginx, maybe its a problem of this version only, but you could add the http:// prefix to the example to make things more streamline on most versions, thanks ^^

Answer (score 24):

You can use RegExp to fetch host name like this

```
server {
    server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;

    location / {
        root   /sites/$domain;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create virtual host for every sub domain.

**For Ex**  you have 2 sub domain abc.xyz.com and abcd.xyz.com , and you want to host it on nginx single instance by proxy_pass then you can simply create virtual host for every sub domain

```
server {
  server_name abc.xyz.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
server {
  server_name abcd.xyz.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

For more information you can refer [here](http://www.zippyout.com/blog/590b740060da301cc602507b/route-different-proxy-based-on-subdomain-request-in-nginx-nginx-subdomain-proxy-pass)