# How Flipkart made their different web and mobile web app with single domain name

Tags: web, web-applications, mobile-website, mobile-application

Anyone who know how **[Flipkart](http://flipkart.com)** made their web and mobile app with single domain name

I am not asking about **Responsive web design**

Beacause **Flipkart** web app is not **responsive** they are using different layouts for mobile and web app by same domain name **flipkart.com**

I knew the old way **for example**

**Web browser**

https://flipkart.com

**Mobile browser**

https://m.flipkart.com

My Question is how they did with single domain.

How they are mainting two diffent apps in single platform

Below is the screenshot of Flipkart web app and mobile web app

Thank you advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple ways

- Configure it on web server (for example NGINX)
- Configure it in domain settings if both application are on different public ip (won't check device, will just check url)
- Configure it on application level with url detection/device detection

I did similar kind of thing with my website once,

1. Device detection on **NGINX**
2. Then redirect traffic to appropriate web-app for different devices

Comment: Hi @Aditya thakur thank you for the answer can we do it without subdomain   check url they did with sub domain http://alvinalexander.com/technology/nginx-redirect-mobile-devices-users-mobile-website

Comment: Yes @MunishKapoor, you can do it however you like. If you are trying to use multiple apps on sub-domain level. Check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064401/route-different-proxy-based-on-subdomain-request-in-nginx

Comment: can you look is it correct way http://serverfault.com/questions/325078/serve-different-files-for-specific-user-agents-using-nginx?newreg=15e93c5f44824d51837546fd9cd5be79