# Nginx servername based proxy routing

Tags: nginx

do you think its possible to route traffic on same port to different locations based on nginx proxy?

**Example:**

app1.node.com(port 123) -> nginx proxy -> 192.168.1.2 (port 123)

app2.node.com(port 123) -> nginx proxy -> 192.168.1.3 (port 123)

If not, is there any other way ho to do that without getting multiple IP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [route different proxy based on subdomain request in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064401/route-different-proxy-based-on-subdomain-request-in-nginx)

Comment: You are using port 123. Is this for an NTP server? Because `server_name` will only work with the Nginx `http` and `mail` subsystems.